# Mac Safari Textarea Issue

Tags: macos

I've done searches on this but can't find any information.  On a Mac in Safari, I have a chat program and on the Customer Service side the textarea does not remove the previously typed answer. So the CSR has to highlight the text and then type her response.  Any suggestions with how to clear the textarea?  OR any suggestions what so ever?  Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot that could be happening here.  For one, what is the chat program written in?

Comment: It looks like it is written in JavaScript, but I will have to do further digging to verify that.

Comment: Are you saying you do not see this same behavior in other browsers, only Safari?

Comment: That was the information that I received earlier, but since I was just shown how to test this it is behaving the same way in FireFox and Chrome, but not in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "chat program" in question was probably written to specifically handle "placeholder" text for IE, since IE doesn't recognize it like most other browsers.

I've tried to write simple jQuery code to get placeholder text to show up in IE before myself, but ended up abandoning it because it caused the effect you're describing in other browsers.

If you don't have direct control over the "chat program", I fear there is probably no way to "fix" this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info and for your time.  I appreciate your help.  I'm fearing the same thing right now.